# Guava Splitter to key value map with splitter character included in strings

Tags: java, regex, guava

I am trying to parse a log file by using Guava splitter. Log file looks like this:

```
appName=XXX clientIp=X.X.X timestamp="2017-06-05T13:22:12-07:00" request="POST /forward HTTP/1.1" statusCode=204 bytesOut=1167 totalTime=0.062 bytesIn=1289 sourceHost=XXXX connId=49936598 connReqs=9 upInstance=XXX:104:XXX-XXX:8664:17F34 upConnectSec=0.052 upAddr="XX.XX.XX:123" upHost="vcv08it-cvcv2801:8464" upHdrTimeSec=0.058 upRespTimeSec=0.058 pid=32561  upStatusCode=204 message="Access Log" corrKey=GMIFCDIKRZR2T4VZQXJA2IT6 upCached=- length=0 partition=XXX location="= /v1/tXXXX" xff="XX.XX.XX.XX" referer="-" user-agent="Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1.1 (Java/1.8.0_131)\" rateLimitCurrentValues="--" rateLimitTimeMs=\"-:-"
```

I used this code to parse it:

```
Map<String, String> parserMap;
parserMap = Splitter.onPattern("\\s(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")
.omitEmptyStrings()
.withKeyValueSeparator(Splitter.onPattern("="))
.split(line);
```

My problem is location="= /v1/tXXXX" field which has '=' inside the string and current withKeyValueSeperator can't parse it. Could you please help me  how I should change patterns to get all the fields correctly?

Comment: I'd be mildly surprised if you can make this work.  You may well need something custom, smart enough to handle this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, no need to use fancy stuffs... with regular regex it's doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Chunk [location="= /v1/tXXXX"] is not a valid entry` is thrown from your code because the `keyValueSeparator` occurs more than once within the chunk. You can adjust your `keyValueSeparator` so that only equal signs followed by your value pattern are matched. e.g.:

```
final String keyPattern = "\\S+";
final String valuePattern = "(\\S+|\"[^\"]*\")";
parserMap = Splitter.onPattern("\\s(?=" + keyPattern + "=" + valuePattern + ")")
        .omitEmptyStrings()
        .withKeyValueSeparator(Splitter.onPattern("=(?=" + valuePattern + ")"))
        .split(line);
```

Note that this won't work if you have something like `key="key=value"` within your line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Guava splitter works, but if you use regular `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, you could use below regex to capture your keys and values:

```
([\w-]+?)=(".*?"|\S+)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9cMdqD/1)**

Java code

```
String text = "your string";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w-]+?)=(\".*?\"|\\S+)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
Map<String, String> parserMap = new HashMap<>();

while (m.find()) {
    String key = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    parserMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Have prepared a IdeOne java working demo here:

https://ideone.com/y8b8di

You can see below samples of the match information

```
Match 1
    Group 1.    0-7     `appName`
    Group 2.    8-11    `XXX`

Match 2
    Group 1.    12-20   `clientIp`
    Group 2.    21-26   `X.X.X`

Match 3
    Group 1.    27-36   `timestamp`
    Group 2.    37-64   `"2017-06-05T13:22:12-07:00"`

Match 4
    Group 1.    65-72   `request`
    Group 2.    73-97   `"POST /forward HTTP/1.1"`
```

Comment: Guava's `Splitter.onPattern` is a splitter internally compiling a `Pattern`. Consider it an improved `String.split(String)`. So the original question is similar to "how can I do this properly with `String.split(String)`?" The regex would be the same.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, good to know. Well, my answer does not focus on splitting pattern but capturing keys/values pattern. I guess OP wants to capture those values

Comment: Indeed. Better a solution unlike the OP has imagined than nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `limit` on the `withKeyValueSeparator` splitter

```
Splitter.onPattern("\\s(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")
    .omitEmptyStrings()
    .withKeyValueSeparator(Splitter.on("=").limit(2).trimResults())
    .split(line);
```

See GitHub issue: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1900

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the answer can be done with a single regex, but a working solution can be made with relative ease:

```
parserMap = Splitter.onPattern("\\s(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")
    .omitEmptyStrings()
    .splitToList(line)
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        s -> s.split("=", 2)[0],  // the first part of split gets the key
        s -> s.split("=", 2)[1]   // everything else is the value
    )
);
```

The trouble with trying to use a regex for `split` is that the inherent goal of split is only to find separators. This is different from normal regex usage, where you can use groups to select things you want; when you split, you're trying to match the things you *don't* want, which gets really messy.